Is it normal that RPC provider will return error message but transaction is actually successful?
I am currently new here at blockchain. I am currently using a subscribed private rpc ankr and Moralis. So, it is normal that rpc will return us some errors but transaction still manages to be made successfully at bscscan? It does not cause error everytime, it happens randomly. Sometime I get Internal JSON RPC error, Already Existed: already known and etc. If that's the case, how should I handle the situation, other than switching to other provider? I have an issue when user makes withdrawal, frontend will show the error message based on the response from the rpc provider but the transaction is actually successful. Therefore, the amount of the user's wallet dAPP doesn't deduct as the function will only trigger when the rpc response message return is successful.
Here's my code
   const maxFeePerGas = gasPrice + maxPriorityFeePerGas;

   const amount = formData.amount;
   const value = ethers.parseEther(amount);
   const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(formData.secretKey, provider);
   let tempErrorData = "";
   let errorLongData = "";

   const txnInfo = await wallet.populateTransaction({
       to: userProfile.wallet_address,
       value: value,
       gasLimit: 21000,
       maxFeePerGas,
       maxPriorityFeePerGas,
       timeout: 500
   }).catch(error => {
       errorLongData = error;
       console.error("Populate 1 Error", error);
       const parsedEthersError = getParsedEthersError(error);
       console.log("parsedEthersError", parsedEthersError);
       tempErrorData = parsedEthersError.context;
   });

   let tx = await wallet.sendTransaction(txnInfo)
       .catch(error => {
           errorLongData = error;
           console.error("error", error);
           const parsedEthersError = getParsedEthersError(error);
           console.log("parsedEthersError", parsedEthersError);
           tempErrorData = parsedEthersError.context;
       });

   console.log("TX", tx);

